# Ceph source code modifiy

Tags: ceph

I want to modify some source code of ceph and then test it inside cloud based simulator.I want to know how to change ceph source code?? as well as which cloud simulator can be used with ceph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the source code by following the instructions at [Contributing Code](https://github.com/ceph/ceph#contributing-code) in the README file of the sources themselves.

After modifying the code you can run **make check** and it will create mini clusters to verify the code works as expected.